# How to eliminate startup dependency in Java 8?

Tags: java, lazy-loading

```
public class Loader {

  static {
    loadFromDB()
  }
  public static void loadFromDB() {
     String db_host = "127.0.0.1"
     int db_port 27017;
     ObjectStore objectStore = ObjectStore(db_host, db_port);
     objectStore.loadDataIntoMap();
  }
}

public class Main {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
     Server server = new Server(host, port);
     server.serve();
     // I dont want to take db_host and db_port as a command line arguments here
   } 
}
```

I understand that static blocks/initializers get executed when they are first referenced however in my Main class I don't want to reference Loader class because I dont want to create a startup dependency by which I mean the Main class should be able to start by itself without depending on the connection to object store is successful or not however the Loader needs to run exactly one time before the server serves the first client request per say.

Comment: Well, it doesn't reference it, so what is the problem/question? Why is the loadFromDB() method static if it's supposed to be called only once, and is already called when the class is initialized?

Comment: Move the values for host and port into a separate configuration and reference it from both the `Main` classes `main` method and your `Loader`. You could even go one step further and set it up with depencency injection. However that is more of an architectural decision.

Comment: you mean host and port or db_host and db_port from the code above? In either case I dont see how that solve the problem? can you provide more insight?

Comment: @JBNizet I am open to changing it to anything. I just want to eliminate startup dependency here. yes loadFromDB() is inside the static block but the Loader is not referenced anywhere so loadFromDB() will never be executed. the moment I reference it in my main I am creating a starup dependency.

Comment: Then don't. Use Loader from the code that needs to get the loaded data. Not from Main. If no code needs to get the loaded data, then loading it is useless anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Static blocks are good way to ensure something runs only once as they run when the class is loaded in memory. 
If you want to replicate that behaviour, you can use static variables.
Static variables are also shared across the class. Singleton pattern should be referenced to ensure that static variable is initialized only once.

Pattern would be
1. Use a static variable to check if the initialization is done.
2. If static var is not set, go into initialization code.
3. If threading is a concern, then use synchronised block. If not then a simple check would do.
4. set the static variable so that you don't run it again.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This still wouldn't solve the problem because I cannot reference Loader in my Main class. static variables are initialized the same way as static blocks.